# Ubuntu 12.04 issue reading hard drive

Tags: 12.04, external-hdd

My laptop used to keep crashing. So I got a new one. The hard drive of my old laptop- they put in a case and I was able to read it as soon as I got home. But now, when I try to mount it, I get an error - `HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed for '/dev/sdb': Invalid argument`
The hard disk (old laptop) was dual boot, with Ubuntu and Windows. My current Ubuntu version is 12.04. I tried recovery with testdisk, photorec etc and managed to get some folders/files, but the critical folders could not be recovered. How can I recover the data? I tried gparted - no use.
fdisk output -

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 320.1 GB, 320072932352 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142446 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
```